# Fetch elements from a dictionary faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a dictionary containing a mapping from color code to class index like the following:

```
color_to_class_idx = {(0, 0, 0) : 0, (180, 120, 120): 1, (80, 50, 50): 2, (140, 140, 140): 3, (4, 250, 7): 4, (150, 6, 51): 5, (0, 102, 200): 6, (233, 255, 7): 7, (255, 31, 0): 8, (120, 120, 120): 9}
```

Now, I have a  list of color code values like the following:

```
list_ = [(0, 0, 0) , (80, 50, 50), (255, 255, 255)]
```

I would like to get another list with the `class_idx`. Note that, in the `list_` there can be color codes for which are not present in the keys of `color_to_class_idx`. For these cases, it should have a default value (e.g. 0). So, the final output would look like - `[0, 2, 0]`

The `list_` could be dimension `345600`. So, speed matters for me. Following is the my implementation:

```
values = np.array([color_to_cls_idx.get(key, 0) for key in segmented_img_list])
```

But it is slow.

TIA

Comment: Where did the "list of color code values" come from in the first place? If you are using Numpy, then you will get the best results by having a Numpy array for those values from the beginning.

Comment: OK. I can use numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little bit better (by ~50%?) by converting most of your data structures to Numpy arrays. Here is an array of dictionary values, addressed by the color coordinates. Note that all elements that are not explicitly updated are 0:

```
lookup = np.zeros((256, 256, 256), dtype=int)
for i in color_to_class_idx:
    lookup[i] = color_to_class_idx[i]
```

Here is the result array:

```
result = np.zeros(len(segmented_img_list))
```

And here is the lookup loop:

```
for i,key in enumerate(segmented_img_list):
    result[i] = lookup[key]
```

Comment: converting segmented_img_list and accessing its dimensions separately gave me more boost. Thanks for your answer.